# Zxing intentIntegration usage

Tags: android, zxing

I am trying to implement a custom barcode scanner.  If I have Zxing installed the app works fine but If I do not the application will error out and you have to force close.  I have added IntentIntegrator.java and IntentResult.java into the SRC folder of my project and changed the package name to point to my package, although Im not sure if that is what I am supposed to do.  It still will not work.  Am I setting this up correctly?  I have found many pages that tell me to use the files but not how to set them up to work.

I would like it to smoothly direct the user to download the zxing app from the market if it is not installed on the client phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not handling `ActivityNotFoundException`, or checking first to see if the app is installed. That is up to you. But, if you used the provided integration code, it would do this all for you. See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

It's not going to launched *your* app though, no.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I do not need it to launch my app as it should have already been launched.  I am very new at android apps.  I am unsure how to check for the ActivityNotFoundException.  I think this is my problem.  is there any examples on how to implement this?

Comment: You use a `try`-`catch` block, but better still, use the integration code I pointed you to. It does it for you inside.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I figured out how to use it, there is just one issue I have.  If you do not have the zxing app you are prompted to download it.  Once it is installed it does not go back to my app.  It stays on the Apps screen with the open and uninstall buttons.  How do I make it so it goes to my activity named EDListActivity?

Comment: It can't be made to go back to any of the previous apps from Market. The user has to come back to your app.